# How to implement PWL or step function in CircuitLab?

Tags: simulation, step-response, pwl

I tried to implement a simple PWL (Piece Wise Linear) function in CircuitLab, and it does not seem to work. It differs slightly from LTspice, which I know how to use. The data points are in CSV (Comma Separated Values), like this:

PWL( 0, 4.8, 0.5, 4.8, 0.501, 24, 1, 24)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI6TqI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I used a time domain simulation with stop time = 1 second, and 1 ms time steps. I get just a steady 4.8V.

I also tried a step function but it seems to have only a single time and voltage data point.

Comment: It's supposed to be one pair of values per line, [as shown and explained here](https://www.circuitlab.com/blog/2013/09/30/piecewise-linear-and-step-csv-sources/).  Alternatively, you can drag a DC voltage source and set the value to one of the [piece-wise functions defined here](https://www.circuitlab.com/docs/expressions/) with [examples shown here](https://www.circuitlab.com/blog/2012/04/13/piecewise-linear-and-piecewise-step-sources/).

Comment: Ah, that works a treat. I could not find that info in the help files. Thanks.